# recover deleted item using LDP

Tags: windows, active-directory

First this is not critical. It is a test environment.

I have server 2012r2 as DC with both domain & functional level at 2012r2. I have AD recycle bin enabled.

I delete a user. I can see that user in deleted objects of AD for recycle bin. I know I can restore it from here.

I would like to restore this user using LDP instead. I open LDP, connect to server, bind. Then options > controls > return deleted objects > view > tree.

So in LDP I see the AD tree & deleted objects container but I don't see the deleted account within it or anywhere else. I've tried different combinations of this by using different articles discussing LDP.

My question is if by having the recycle bin option enabled at the functional level I have does this prevent LDP from showing me the deleted account? Can someone try this in a their test environment & see if they get the same result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, having AD recycle bin enabled does not prevent LDP from showing you the tombstoned (deleted) object.  I have verified this just a few minutes ago.  I have AD recycle bin enabled and was able to find my deleted object in AD Admin center and via the LDP tool.

The tool can be used only if the Deleted object is under tombstoned life.  If the deleted object has been "garbage collected" then LDP will not show the deleted object.

Also follow the steps in this Technet article on using LDP to retrieve a deleted object.  It lists *all* the steps for searching for a deleted object via LDP.  Blog posts and tech articles on other websites skip some steps.
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc978013.aspx

Comment: I like the Seinfeld reference, haha. You were 100% correct. That link actually showed me the correct way to see deleted objects using LDP. The other articles showed how to actually show the deleted objects under "deleted objects" container in the tree at the left of LDP. This method you linked to just dumps a list/query on the right hand side of LDP. I would prefer the first method but as long as I get a list I'm happy. Thanks.

Comment: Yes I am a long time Seinfeld fan.  :)  You are welcome.  I'm glad my answer helped you!

Comment: One follow up question. I thought recovering items with LDP pretty much lost their attributes like group membership. It is only supposed to allow you to recover the item so it can have the original SID. The item I recovered still had its group membership. Was this improved in 2012 or with recycle bin?

Comment: I thought the same about LDP. I haven't recovered a deleted object with LDP in server 2012. I'll have to research that. Interesting.